# How can I print date of birth in to the invoice pdf?

Tags: invoice

Hey guys so i enabled date of birth from the admin but now i need to add to pdf format in to the invoice... 
If somebody have a solution pls help. 
Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: Please add your version, technology and some details. From where you are generating this pdf

Comment: @VivekKhandelwal i use 1.9  community i add it the email in to the invoice but i dont have a clue how to add the dob.

Comment: I can give you an idea but you have to do it your own way.
Go to 
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php here you can find the getPdf() function and this function actually call the data on pdf.
Now go to 
/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php
here you can have those functions used in above file. Create your own function here and call it in the above function

Comment: ok @VivekKhandelwal thats sounds good

Comment: Please don't edit the core files directly that is not the way we work in magento. Trying overridding it in local

Comment: Could you please add your solution as an answer @VivekKhandelwal?

Comment: @AnnaVölkl try my solution bellow it works for me

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to show the dob in to the invoice:

Don't erase this just add this code below this code:

```
$billingAddress  =  $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf'));

$billingAddress2 = substr($order->getCustomerDob(), 0,10);
$billingAddress = $this->_formatAddress($order->getBillingAddress()->format('pdf').Mage::helper("sales")->__('Date of Birth: '. $billingAddress2));
```

path: `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

i hoped it helps!

Comment: Editing the core files is not best practise as you will lose these changes when you upgrade to a newer Magento version later. It's better to make a rewrite of a subclass (as you cannot rewrite abstract classes).